# Python Parse JSON Response from URL

Tags: python, json, http, python-requests

I'm am wanting to get information about my Hue lights using a python program. I am ok with sorting the information once I get it, but I am struggling to load in the JSON info. It is sent as a JSON response. My code is as follows:

```
import requests
import json

response= requests.get('http://192.168.1.102/api/F5La7UpN6XueJZUts1QdyBBbIU8dEvaT1EZs1Ut0/lights')
data = json.load(response)   
print(data)
```

When this is run, all I get is the error:

```
in load return loads(fp.read(),    
Response' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Comment: You should read up on requests' API, it exposes parsed JSON for you. The response isn't just a string. This is actually in literally the first example in the docs: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are passing in the actual response which consists of more than just the content.  You need to pull the content out of the response:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://github.com/timeline.json')
print r.text

# The Requests library also comes with a built-in JSON decoder,
# just in case you have to deal with JSON data

import requests
r = requests.get('https://github.com/timeline.json')
print r.json
```

http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/requests/using-requests-in-python

Looks like it will parse the JSON for you already...

Answer (score 1):

Use [response.content](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#binary-response-content) to access response content and [json.loads](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.loads) method instead of json.load:

```
data = json.loads(response.content)  
print data
```